# Why does python need you to define a properties's existence?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have the following for my code (working):

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

    if 'Speed' in own and 'Recoil_Level' in own and 'Proportion_Size' in own:

        speed = own['Speed']
        level = own['Recoil_Level']
        size = own['Proportion_Size']

    else:
        print('No properties found in Weapon_Recoil_Level_Determiner')
        return

    own['Recoil_Level']= speed / size
    print("recoil level: ", own['Recoil_Level'])    

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

Also, I have the following:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

        speed = own['Speed']
        level = own['Recoil_Level']
        size = own['Proportion_Size']

    else:
        print('No properties found in Weapon_Recoil_Level_Determiner')
        return

    own['Recoil_Level']= speed / size
    print("recoil level: ", own['Recoil_Level'])    

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

Why won't the second one work? I am asking this because when I write scripts that include **many** properties, I do not want to have a really long, ugly paragraph saying "if x in own and if y in own and..." and so on. How can I make the second script work?

Comment: @zeffii I am having trouble with the code, I am not understanding how to cover it up correctly.

Comment: the second snippet is not correctly formed python code. Look carefully at it. You have an else without an if

Comment: @zeffii Ahh! Me too. Seems funny. I was in a rush and couldn't think of anything, but you are fine. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general Python question which isn't specific to Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think this is more a Python specific question, maybe an answer is still useful for style.

It is possible to use the `all` keyword

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

    speed = own.get('Speed')
    level = own.get('Recoil_Level')
    size = own.get('Proportion_Size')

    if not all([speed, level, size]):
        print('No properties found in Weapon_Recoil_Level_Determiner')
        return

    own['Recoil_Level'] = speed / size
    print("recoil level: ", own['Recoil_Level'])    

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

[`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is useful because it will return None if the key isn't present.